# what difference between direct pointer and indirect pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

pointer to a struct

code that can not work

```
struct node
{
    /* data */
    int data;
};

void addnode(struct node* n)
{
    n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("value of pointer n = %p",&n);
    (*n).data = 9;
}
int main()
{   
    struct node * n1 = NULL;
    addnode(n1);
    printf("data is %d\n",n1->data);
}
```

but the code below is fine

```
struct node
{
    /* data */
    int data;
};

void addnode(struct node ** n1)
{
    // the address of struct
    *n1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("address of pointer &n1 = %p\n",&n1);
    printf("address of pointer *n1 = %p\n",*n1);
    (*n1)->data = 99;
}
int main()
{   
    struct node * n1 = NULL;
    //pass the address of pointer instead of value of it
    addnode(&n1);
    printf("address of pointer &n1 = %p\n",&n1); // self address
    printf("address of pointer *n1 = %p\n",&(*n1)); // the address of struct
    printf("data is %d\n",n1->data);
}
```

what makes me confused is why the indirect pointer as a parameter is working, instead of the direct pointer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed, I once made one as community wiki, see the linked duplicate. A list of good dupe targets can be found in the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) below FAQ.

Comment: In the first version, you just passed the value of `n1` to a function, so `n` just got assigned `NULL` at the beginning. Afterwards you did `n = ... malloc`, which is an unrelated address to the original `n1`.  The second version `*n1 =....` writes into the address of what you passed. Also note that your function don't change `&n1` even though it's changed `n1` . So, it's the same value as before you did `addnode(&n1)`, till the very end of the `main`. So: First version: you passed n1 =>  you can't change n1 from the function
Second version: you passed &n1 => you can't change &n1 inside of it

Answer (score 1):

The 'indirect' pointer, as you called it, is actually 'a pointer to your pointer variable'.

If you inspect the value of `n1` in your debugger, you will see, in your first example, that it will remain NULL (because you did not assign a new value to it).

In the second example however, you assign a value to the variable by accessing it's address.

Your first code can work too if it looks like this:

```
struct node
{
    /* data */
    int data;
};

struct node* addnode()
{
    struct node* n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("value of pointer n = %p",&n);
    n->data = 9;
    return n;
}
int main()
{   
    struct node * n1 = NULL;
    n1 = addnode();
    printf("data is %d\n",n1->data);
}
```

Comment: I will have a try.thanks folks